# Creating first angularjs SPA with VS2015

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I am new to AngularJS and need some advice on how to structure a SPA with Web API for an external search application

Di I have to use
•MVC / razor views (leave all routing and rendering to Angular)? or just use 1 VS2015 app [use angularjs SPA template for VS2015 or just an empty web application with angular file and a webapi project under same solution?

any examples would be helpful to understand

For angular structure I am reading [Google best practice](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) and [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Comment: Razor views are prefered to use if you are building a C# MVC app. When building a angularjs SPA then just use HTML and angularjs for frontend and web api or any other api to provide the spa with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think what you ran into now. I can suggest two of the ways you can choose.

1. If you want to keep your backend and frontend together you can go for angularjs SPA template for VS2015. It would come with the build pipelines, bundles and everything you'd need. Now you can choose to render your single page of angular to be rendered with a MVC razor view (if you want to have any mechanisms where you'd want to include your dependencies through the razor view) or just go with a blank html and web api controllers on the back. But you'd end up using one environment for all and I think that's best if you're building the full project.
2. Now, for the other way around, you can start with an web api project. You can instantiate your angular project with it or somewhere else. You can use [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) or any scaffolding tool you like and use your own JS toolings you'd like to use. You can do the same in the VS project too but this approach is better if you want to keep the frontend and backend flavor separate.

And I'd suggest using typescript too.

Comment: In option 1, one suggestion is to use `ASP.Net Web Application` then choose `Empty` project template. Set up angular structure in it andthen add `WebApi Controller`.cs files to the project?

Comment: Technically, yes. And if you want more hands off approach, please have a look in [here](http://iranreyes.com/starting-angularjs-project-with-visual-studio/).

And, if you have flexibility and particularly adventurous, you can even give [Asp.net Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/angular.html) a chance.